# UITextField doesn't work when added via code

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

I am having a problem with adding UITextField via code. When I use this simple code inside empty view controller all work fine:

```
let textField = UITextField(frame: CGRect(x: 10, y: 10, width: 200, height: 20))
textField.text = "test"
scrollView.addSubview(textField)
```

But inside my custom `UIScrollView` for some reason it won't work (editing don't start).

I tried to set `userInteractionEnabled` for `textField` and also for superview but that doesn't help. I am not sure how I can debug to see which property is blocking editing. No keyboard is popping up; I can't type inside simulator and/or make selections. What is also strange that other controls such as UIButton work perfect and receive touches.

As can be seen, I didn't add delegate, but it works perfectly good on empty UIViewController without it.

`po textField.canBecomeFirstResponder()` returns true.

Comment: click on textField and press commnd + K.

Comment: Keyboard is not showing (via Menu or CMD+K). It act like it is completely disabled. You can't even click on it. I am starting to worry that my layout is blocking it somehow, but don't know how to debug it. Btw. control is fully visible on screen.

Comment: I think your UIScrollView is "stealing" the tap gesture and it is not getting to the UITextField

Comment: @IcaroNZ: That is why I suspect too. It puzzles me why UIButton's are working fine. Do you maybe have some tips how can I debug this? Thanks.

Comment: @user3758317 have you try the new viewer debug? It my show if there is some view on top of your label

Comment: @IcaroNZ: Now I saw some artefacts of superview inside view debugger. I didn't notice that superview didn't gather height :( 99% this will be the issue. I will try to fix it now. Thank you.

Comment: @IcaroNZ: Yes, that was the issue. I didn't notice 1px hairline of superview that he didn't set own height. ClipToBounds was false so it look that all is fine of textField as sub-view. Thank you man, you helped me a lot!

Comment: @user3758317 I am glad I could help, I add some stuff I found about this, maybe it will be a good reading for you too I sure did learn some new things.

Comment: You should make sure to avoid putting the solution to your problem in the question; instead, put it in a self-answer or (in some cases) add as a comment to an answer that led you to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was reading [apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIScrollView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIScrollView/delaysContentTouches) and I find this:

> **If the value of this property is true, the scroll view delays handling the touch-down gesture until it can determine if scrolling is
>   the intent. If the value is false , the scroll view immediately calls
>   touchesShouldBegin:withEvent:inContentView:. The default value is
>   true.**

And This from [apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIView/hitTest:withEvent:):

> This method traverses the view hierarchy by calling the
>   pointInside:withEvent: method of each subview to determine which
>   subview should receive a touch event. If pointInside:withEvent:
>   returns true, then the subview’s hierarchy is similarly traversed
>   until the frontmost view containing the specified point is found. If a
>   view does not contain the point, its branch of the view hierarchy is
>   ignored.

Answer (score 1):

Set scrollView.delaysContentTouches to NO.

You may have to come up with your own logic for turning it off/on depending on whether or not accidentally touching a control inside the scrollView becomes an issue.

You can also just tap and hold on the textField without scrolling. It should bring up the keyboard, but most users probably won't know to do that.

Comment: It was not issue in my case, but didn't know about this property. I will use it more.